# htaccess redirect to remove duplicate pages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I'm very new to this thing with htaccess rules.

I basically want two things.

1. Redirect *exampledomain.com* to *www.exampledomain.com*. This works, the web host that is used had a FAQ page where they suggested the code I use. What *doesn't* work is this:
2. Remove the way to access the "example" page from both "/index.php?p=example" and "/?p=example" to get better search engine ranks. If this means accessing that page from something like "/example", that's a bonus.

I basically want to remove the duplicate links that is caused by the /index.php-variant to get higher search engine ranks. Having prettier links isn't required, just a bonus, the most important thing is that I need to remove the duplicate links.

Here's the code anyway:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exampledomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.exampledomain.com$1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /?p=$1 [L]
```

Have I misunderstood the [L/R=301/*]-flags totally?

EDIT: Ok, to clarify. I want to remove duplicate urls to get higher search engine ranks. What my code above apparently did was to add yet *another* url to access the same page. Since I only want one way, is there any way to redirect instead of just pointing the "prettified" link to the original?

When I think about it, would a redirection of *exampledomain.com/index.php* to *exampledomain.com* do the trick?

Thanks guys so far, sorry for being bad at explaining. :)

Comment: You tried putting bottom two rules before RewriteCond?